# C not implicitly converting int to char

Tags: c, ascii, implicit-conversion

```
printf("%c", (plaintext[i] + keyword[(count % keywordLength)]) % 26;);
```

Where `plaintext` and `keyword` are of the `string` datatype (`char *`), `count` is an int, and `keywordLength` is the returned value of `strlen(keyword)`. When I use the integer format specifier, the integers print. However, I want it to print as letters, but it prints nothing when I use the character format specifier. I`m not sure why.

For my example, the following are true:

```
char * plaintext = "hello";
char * keyword = "abc";
```

Comment: **hint:** what are the first `26` (0-25) characters of the [ASCII table](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)?

Comment: That you _cannot see_ what's being printed doesn't necessarily mean nothing is being printed.

Comment: What ForceBru said. Generally you can get better information in cases like this if you surround your format specifier with text. `printf("f%cf", ...);` (just to convince you something is being printed)

Comment: Not visible characters. . .  I`ll double check that line. .

Comment: OT: "*the `string` datatype (`char *`)*" there is no "string" data type in C. `char*` is a pointer to a variable of data type `char`.

Comment: Looks like you just want something like `'a' + ((plaintext[i] + keyword[(count % keywordLength)]) % 26)` to bring it back into the `'a'` to `'z'` range.

Comment: `char*` is not "the `string` datatype". In fact there is no `string` data type in C. A *string* is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." A `char*` may or may not be a *pointer to a string*. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.1.1, paragraph 1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question should be tagged with [tag:cs50] because one of the sins CS50 commits is using `typedef char *string;` in its header `<cs50.h>`, and this looks like Vigenere Cipher work, which is the topic of one of the PSets in CS50.  It is mildly debatable whether [tag:vigenere] should be added; I favour not doing so at the moment.

Comment: Yeah it is. I wanted to lean CS so I`m using Wayback machine to look at old CS50 stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Code is printing control characters with:

```
printf("%c", (plaintext[i] + keyword[(count % keywordLength)]) % 26);
```

Code relies on `printf("%c", 0);` printing a letter, when it certainly prints a control character - which may not be visible.

Subtle note: Code is relying on `plaintext[i], keyword[]` to only contain non-negative values.  Should the sum of `plaintext[i] + keyword[(count % keywordLength)]` be less than 0, that `sum % 26` will also be negative.

To print an ASCII value in the [A-Z], add `'A'` or  `'a'` [@lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081097/c-not-implicitly-converting-int-to-char/46081824#comment79124154_46081097).

```
int sum = plaintext[i] + keyword[(count % keywordLength)];
printf("%c", (sum % 26) + 'A');
```

To pedantically handle negative `sum` and to be highly portable:

```
int sum = plaintext[i] + keyword[(count % keywordLength)];
// mod math, even for negative values
sum = ((sum % 26) + 26) % 26;
// Print letter, even when encoding is not ASCII
printf("%c", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[sum]);
```